# Using the Consolibyte PHP SDK for QuickBooks, how do identify which client is sending a call from the Web Connector?

Tags: php, desktop, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I want to use a single server endpoint for the Web Connector, but connect from there to individual client databases.

However, when the locally installed Web Connector sends a message to the SOAP server, it seems to send three successive messages, only the *third* of which contains anything that can identify the client - the username and password.

I cannot log into the correct database, which in this case means creating a correct `$dsn` string, without anything identifying which database I should be logging into.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Connector follows a very specific protocol that Intuit has defined, and that protocol does *not* have any support for identifying who is connecting *beyond the use of the username*.

That means that for the initial two HTTP requests (`clientVersion` and `serverVersion`) there is *no way for you to tell who is connecting*.

If you need to identify who is connecting *prior to authentication*, you need to do something beyond what the Web Connector protocol itself offers. This could be as simple as a query string added to your endpoint. e.g.:

- `https://your-website.com/web_connector.php?connecting_account=account_A`

vs.

- `https://your-website.com/web_connector.php?connecting_account=account_B`

And then in your code:

```
switch ($_GET['connecting_account'])
{
   case ... (@todo connect to the correct database here)
}
```